# OpenLayers-5 reproject OSM in a custom projection

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

Following [OpenLayers examples](https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html), I try to reproject OSM in a custom projection. The view is empty, no OSM tile is downloaded.

index.js :

```
import {get as getProjection} from 'ol/proj';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import 'ol/ol.css';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import proj4 from 'proj4';
import {register} from 'ol/proj/proj4';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS';
import View from 'ol/View';
import * as Gp from 'geoportal-extensions-openlayers';

proj4.defs('EPSG:2154','+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3' + 
'+x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');
register(proj4);
var franceProjection = getProjection('EPSG:2154');

 var couches = [
  new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
})
];
var map = new Map({
 target: 'map',
 layers: couches,
 view: new View({
projection: 'EPSG:2154',
center: [524326, 6700656],
zoom: 14
 })     
});
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "iliad_ol5.3.0",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "parcel index.html",
"build": "parcel build --public-url . index.html"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"geoportal-extensions-openlayers": "^3.0.7",
"ol": "^5.3.0",
"proj4": "^2.6.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
},
"description": ""
}
```

I know that it is a basic projection issue but even that's hard for me.

Comment: In map view specification leave out `map.setView(` call and retain just view definition `new View( …`.

Comment: same result : view empty and in network debug window no tile downloaded (FF).

Answer (score 2):

The code below works without any problems, so there must be problem either in your environment (imports) or in your code after removing `map.setView(` function.

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:2154','+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3' + 
'+x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
var franceProjection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:2154');

var couches = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  })
];
var map = new ol.Map({
 target: 'map',
 view: new ol.View({
  projection: 'EPSG:2154',
  center: [524326, 6700656],
  zoom: 14
 }),
 layers: couches
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried you code and the result was nearly the same : map empty but blue buttons + and - from OL disappeared  ; I rebuilt the dev env as recommanded on OL https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html site, used my code in the first message but nothing changed, except the comeback of blue buttons...  I can add OSM in 3857 but as soon as I want to use `EPSG:2154` the map is empty.

Comment: If there are no errors in the console and all the files all loading correctly, then I'm at loss here since I don't have the same environment. Obviously there is some problem with proj4.

Comment: I tried with proj4 2.5.0 but no tile dowloaded as well. They are not listed in network debug window.